# Error when adding components for the Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have already generated components for my project. They worked perfectly fined. But there is some issues when I recently tried to a new component for Angular project.

PS

> E:\Projects\NodeJsTestings\Library\AngularApp\src\app> ng g c
>   suggestion Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 801

But Everything seems to be OK as I didn't made any changes for the JSON package as well. I can't figure out what's wrong when adding this new component.
[image]

Comment: can you show your package.json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run the command where your **`angular-cli.json`** resides.

so it should be inside your app folder

```
E:\Projects\NodeJsTestings\Library\AngularApp> ng g c suggestion
```

Comment: PS E:\Projects\NodeJsTestings\Library\AngularApp\src\app> cd ..
PS E:\Projects\NodeJsTestings\Library\AngularApp\src> cd ..
PS E:\Projects\NodeJsTestings\Library\AngularApp> ng g c suggestion
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 801

Comment: check where the angular cli json is in your app

Comment: I can't figure out the what is the wrong with this Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 801